# Sequence of quadratic polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Let $P_n$ be a sequence of Quadratic polynomials on $[0,1]$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P_n(a_i) = b_i$ for $i = 1,2,3$ where $b_i$ are real numbers. Then

1) $P_n$ converges pointwise  in $[0,1]$

2) $P_n^{'}$ converges pointwise  in $[0,1]$

3)$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n(\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}}{3})$ does not exist

4)$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n^{'}(\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}}{3})$ does not exist

Give me some hint, how to understand the limit function just by knowing it vaues at $a_1,a_2,a_3$.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are $a_i$ mutually distinct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_i$ are mutually distinct, then you can rewrite your polynomials as

$$P_n(x) = \frac{(x-a_2)(x-a_3)}{(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)}P_n(a_1)+\frac{(x-a_1)(x-a_3)}{(a_2-a_1)(a_2-a_3)}P_n(a_2)+\frac{(x-a_1)(x-a_2)}{(a_3-a_1)(a_3-a_2)}P_n(a_3).$$
I think this expression will allow you to answer all those questions. If you still ahve troubles, ask in comments.

**edit**

So, for a fixed $x$ tha value of $P_n(x)$ is a linear combination (the coefficients of this linear combination do not depend on $n$) of the values $P_n(a_i)$, same goes for $P_n'(x)$, therefore if $\forall i\ P_n(a_i)$ converge, then so do  $P_n(x)$ and $P_n'(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. nice. So both the sequences $P_n$ and $P_n^{'}$ has  pointwise limit. is this what , we are conclude from your expression?

Comment: How the existence of limit on just these three points make sure that the limit exists every where? can you explain little bit?

Comment: @GA316 see edit.

Comment: I need one more clarification. please tell why it is not enough to have the existence of the limit on two numbers, say only on $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Comment: @GA316 imagine that $P_n(0)=0$, $P_n(1)=1$, $P_n(1/2)=-n$, then $P_n(x)\to-\infty$ $\forall x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: nice example. Got it. thanks.